# Flask, SQLAlchemy, Can't compare a collection to an object or collection; use contains() to test for membership

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to create an **Alert** table, and add a **Command** table to it. I want the name of the alert and the command associated with it to be displayed in the index page together. But I cannot get it. Could you look at my code and tell me my mistake?

```
jointable = db.Table('jointable',
    db.Column('command_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('commands.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('alert_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('alerts.id'), primary_key=True))


class Command(db.Model):
    __tablename__='commands'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    cname = db.Column(db.Text)
    alertses = db.relationship('Alert', secondary=jointable, backref=db.backref('commands', lazy = 'select'))
    alert_id = db.Column(db.Integer)



class Alert(db.Model):
    __tablename__='alerts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    aname = db.Column(db.Text)
```

If my request is like this: **Command = Command.query.join(Alert.commands).filter(Alert.commands == Command.id).all() , I get the error: **Can't compare a collection to an object or collection; use contains() to test for membership**

If my request is like this:**Command = Command.query.join(Alert.commands).filter(Alert.id == Command.alertses).all())**
I get: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqoTi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didn't mention it clearly but ill assume that the relationship is one to many.

if this is not the case take a look at - [sql-alchemy relationships doc](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html)

**hope youll find this snippet helpful, notice i changed some naming conventions & used the Base class of sqlalchemy**

```py
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Command(Base): #child
    __tablename__='command'
    id = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = db.Column(Text)
    alert_id = db.Column(Integer, ForeignKey('alert.id'))


class Alert(Base): #parent
    __tablename__='alert'
    id = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = db.Column(Text)
    command = relationship("Command")
```

In order to query a specific alert & the related commands try this -

`alert = Alert.query.get(id)`

For all -

`alerts - Alert.query.all()`

the commands collection will be under alert.command

EDIT:
If it all about the rendering part try this under your desired route -

```py
alerts = Alert.query.all() 
return render_template('index.html', alerts=alerts)
```

in the index.html -

```
{% for alert in alerts %}
    <div>{{ alert.name }}</div>
    {% for command in alert.command &}
        <p>{{command.name}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, for you reply. And I am very sorry, my code was displayed incomplete, I fixed it. I assumed many-to-many, and created an association table. I tried your code and it works as well as mine. But my problem is different. I want the index page to display all Alerts and commands belonging to this particular Alert in one line. Code from page index: ** <p> <b> Alertname: </b> {{Alertname.name}} <b>  {% for Command in Command%} <b> Command name: </b> {{Command.name}} {% endfor%} {% endfor %} **